# emacs doesn't backwards delete words with M-Del

Tags: keymap

I'm using iTerm2 and have my `left option` key set to `+Esc`. I can backwards delete words in `bash` with `M-Del` (`option-Del`) but in emacs, `M-Del` doesn't backwards delete words, it just changes the location of the cursor/point ~150 lines down in the text and then displays `Mark set` in the echo area.

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: To what function is `option-Del` bound? Use `C-h k` to find out.

Comment: When I type `C-h k` and then `M-Del` it says `C-M-h runs the command mark-defun`. This doesn't make sense to me, why is it registering the `C` and `h` keys when I'm pressing `M-Del`?

Comment: Sometimes a function may be bound to both C-M-<something> and M-<something>, but Emacs would translate M-<something> into C-M-<something> before calling the function. I have no idea though as to how Del can be translated into h. Could you by any chance load some init file which remaps keys? I.e. do you see the same behavior in `emacs -q`?

Comment: `DEL` and `C-h` are traditionally the same thing. In the ASCII character set, all the control characters are at the bottom of the character range, from 0 to 31. The control key on the keyboard just masked out the top 3 bits of the character you typed, leaving just a number from 0 to 31, allowing you to type any control character you wanted. Thus we use `C-j` for a line-feed and `C-l` for a form-feed and so on. Technically on modern computers you can distinguish between `DEL` and `C-h`, but Emacs predates that.

Comment: @db48x This 3 bits masking stuff is interesting.  Could you provide some link documenting that? (not an emacs question anyway).

Comment: Sure, see section 5.25 of [the manual for a Model 33 Teletype](https://archive.org/stream/bitsavers_teletype33riterSetsTechnicalManualSep74_30729703/310B_Vol_1_33_Teletypewriter_Sets_Technical_Manual_Sep74#page/n103/mode/2up) for an early example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in my iTerm2 settings. I had the `Option - Delete` mapped to send certain hex codes in the "Keys" tab in settings. NB, there are key mapping settings in the "Keys" and "Profiles" tabs in settings, so you could have key mappings in either place doing something with unintended effects.